# Does single floating point operation calculated at higher precision and immediately truncated always produce identical result?

Tags: floating-point, deterministic

Does single floating point operation (like a+b, a-b, a*b or a/b) calculated at higher precision (80 bits) and immediately truncated (to 32 bits) always produce identical result to calculation made at original type's precision (32 bits)?

Or could the least significant bit be different in the result? Why?

EDIT: Part of example from [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2009/03/25/is-floating-point-math-deterministic/)

```
float tmp;  // 32 bit precision temporary variable
push a;     // converts 32 to 64 bit
push b;     // converts 32 to 64 bit
multiply;   // 64 bit computation
pop tmp;    // converts result to 32 bits
```

Author of this example explains this code like this:

> Even though the multiply and add instructions are using 64 bit internal precision, the results are immediately converted back to 32 bit format, so this does not affect the result.

**So what I am asking, is this always true? Single operation like this will always produce identical result to the last bit no matter on what platform?**

I am programming in C#, where we have no control with what precision floating-point operations are done.

From C# specification:

> Floating-point operations may be performed with higher precision than
>   the result type of the operation. For example, some hardware
>   architectures support an “extended” or “long double” floating-point
>   type with greater range and precision than the double type, and
>   **implicitly perform all floating-point operations using this higher
>   precision type**.

And I need to know if single operations on floating-points (like C# example below) are deterministic.

```
double a = 2.5d;
double b = 0.1d;
myClassInstance.someDoubleField = a*b; // value should be converted out of extended precision
```

**So is this `someDoubleField` value going to be identical on all platforms?**

Comment: Do you mean truncated as in "rounded towards zero"? Or are you in fact referring to precision reduction by rounding "towards nearest or even"? For the latter, published work shows that you will get the same result for addition/subtraction, multiplication, division, square root, and reciprocal square root, if the higher precision provides at least 2n+k bits vs a lower n-bit precision (where k <= 3), meaning the condition is satisfied by performing the operation in IEEE-754 double precision , correctly-rounded, and rounding  the result to IEEE-754 single precision. I don't have references handy.

Comment: Truncated as in when the value is popped out of extended precision. I have updated the question with additional explanation.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking here. You. are comparing the given sequence of operations to what?

Comment: @EJP To how it behaves in case if higher FP precision is used during FP calculation, compared to if same precision (same as FP type used) is used during calculation

Comment: [For future readers.] A more formal analysis which extends the Figueroa's results to include other bases (including decimal floating point) is available in > Roux, P. (2014). Innocuous Double Rounding of Basic Arithmetic Operations. Journal of Formalized Reasoning, 7(1), 131–142. https://doi.org/10.6092/issn.1972-5787/4359

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's established in this paper:

> Samuel A. Figueroa, "When is double rounding innocuous?" *ACM SIGNUM Newsletter*, Volume 30 Issue 3, July 1995 doi:[10.1145/221332.221334](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/221332.221334)

The main results is that if the input type has *p*-bit significands, and the number of bits in the significand of the computation type is at least 2*p*+2 bits, the elementary operations `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and `sqrt` will all be correctly rounded when truncated back.

An IEEE754 `binary32` number (i.e. the typical C `float` type) has a 24-bit significand, so it is in fact sufficient to use `binary64` (i.e. typical C `double`) which has a 53-bit significand. In fact, this is a pretty common trick [used by JavaScript compilers](https://blog.mozilla.org/javascript/2013/11/07/efficient-float32-arithmetic-in-javascript/) to make use of `binary32` operations when the language itself only has a `binary64` type.

Comment: I have updated the question with additional explanation as njuffa asked for additional clarification of what I meant. So if I may ask, is it also the same when elementary operation is done on two 64-bit double using 80-bit extended precision?

Comment: @zigzag Note the "2p+2" bits of precision requirement (2p+3 if you include reciprocal square root). It is clearly not satisfied when you consider rounding 80-bit extended precision (with a 64-bit significand/mantissa) down to double precision.

Comment: No (x87 80-bit "long doubles" have a 64-bit significand, so the property isn't satisified). You probably need to use compiler options; C# has `/fp:precise` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately C# has no such compiler option. `/fp:precise` from that link is for C++ compiler only. 

So if I understand correctly such single elementary operation in C# would be deterministic when using 32-bit `float` values, but non-deterministic when using 64-bit `double` values?

Comment: For the "2p+3" requirement for reciprocal square root, see: Cristina Iordache and David W. Matula: "On Infinitely Precise Rounding for Division, Square Root, Reciprocal and Square Root Reciprocal". In *Proceedings of the 14th IEEE Symposium on Computer Arithmetic (ARITH-14)* , pp. 233–240

Comment: @zigzag I don't use C#, however I understand that this language is used mostly (exclusively?) on Windows, and there the program environment is set up such that the x87 precision control defaults to *double precision*, not extended precision as under Linux. The reason for this is presumably that Microsoft would like to avoid exposing programmers to difficult to address double-rounding issues

Comment: By using Mono runtime it can also run on Linux, OSX, Android, iOS. So this calculation needs to be consistent across all this platforms. I am discussing with an author of fixed point library if conversions between fixed point type & FP types (as currently implemented) work deterministicaly on all platforms or not. I can post source code of methods in question if you like.

Comment: Such bit-wise floating-point consistency seems unlikely as long as x87 is part of the mix (it's the only commonly used floating-point processor that provides extended precision). Your chances are pretty good if the hardware provides strictly IEEE-754 `binary32` and `binary64` computation, but even there you could hit snags depending on whether the floating-point unit operates in non-IEEE-754 flush-to-zero mode.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise those were the C++ docs. In general, you should be okay, as most compilers will use SSE instructions or 64-bit mode on x87: you could also add some inline assembly to ensure this is the case.

Comment: Thank you both very much! I think that cleared things up.

Comment: I would like just to add one special case I learned about: For multiplication/division, if one of the FP numbers is power of two number (2^x), significant/mantissa won't change during calculation. Only exponent will change (point will move). So rounding will never happen (and we don't have to worry about 2p+2 bits rule).

Comment: Example: A number like 2^32 is represented as (exponent: 32, mantissa: 1). If we multiply this with another float (exp, man), the result is (exp + 32, man * 1). For division, the result is (expo - 32, man * 1). Multiplying the mantissa by 1 doesn't change the mantissa, so it doesn't matter how many bits it has.